# T-SQL Matching process using only provided fields

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, matching

I am trying to write a stored procedure to match lists of physicians with existing records in our database based off of the information provided to us by our clients. Currently we use MS Access to join manually based on the given identifiers, but this process tends to be tedious and overly time consuming, hence the desire to automate it.

What I am trying to do is create a temporary table that contains all columns that could potentially be matched on, and then run through a series of matching queries using the fields as join conditions to get our identifier to pass back.

For instance, the available matching fields are Name, NPI, MedicaidNum, and DOB so I would write something like:

```
UPDATE Temp
SET Temp.RECID = Phy.RECID
FROM TempTable Temp
INNER JOIN Physicians Phy
ON Phy.Name = Temp.Name
AND Phy.NPI = Temp.NPI
AND Phy.MedicaidNum = Temp.MedicaidNum
AND Phy.DOB = Temp.DOB

UPDATE Temp
SET Temp.RECID = Phy.RECID
FROM TempTable Temp
INNER JOIN Physicians Phy
ON Phy.Name = Temp.Name
AND Phy.NPI = Temp.NPI
AND Phy.MedicaidNum = Temp.MedicaidNum
WHERE Temp.RECID IS NULL

...etc
```

The problem lies in the fact that there about 15 different identifiers which could potentially be provided and clients usually only provide three or four per record set. So by the time null values are accounted for, there are potentially over a hundred different queries that need to be written to match on only half a dozen provided fields.

I am thinking that there may be a way to pass in a variable (or variables) which indicate which columns are actually provided with the data set, and then write a dynamic join statement and/or where clause, but I do not know if this will work in T-SQL. Something like:

```
DECLARE @Field1
DECLARE @Field2
....
UPDATE Temp
SET Temp.RECID = Phy.RECID
FROM TempTable Temp
INNER JOIN Physicians Phy
ON Phy.@Field1 = Temp.@Field1
AND Phy.@Field2 = Temp.@Field2
```

This way I would limit the number of queries I need to write, and only need to worry about the number of fields I am matching, rather then which specific ones. Perhaps there is a better approach to this problem however?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, but be warned this method is super prone to SQL injection.  It's just to illustrate the principle of how to do something like this.  I leave it up to you what you want to do with it.  For this code, I made the proc take three fields:

```
CREATE PROC DynamicUpdateSQLFromFieldList   @Field1 VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
                                            @Field2 VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
                                            @Field3 VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
                                            @RunMe BIT = 0
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(1000);

    SELECT  @SQL = 'UPDATE Temp
                    SET Temp.RECID = Phy.RECID  
                    FROM TempTable Temp
                    INNER JOIN Physicians Phy ON ' +
                    COALESCE('Phy.' + @Field1 + ' = Temp.' + @Field1 + ' AND ', '') +
                    COALESCE('Phy.' + @Field2 + ' = Temp.' + @Field2 + ' AND ', '') +
                    COALESCE('Phy.' + @Field3 + ' = Temp.' + @Field3, '') + ';';

    IF @RunMe = 0               
        SELECT @SQL AS SQL;
    ELSE
        EXEC(@SQL)

END
```

I've added a debug mode flag just so you can see the SQL if you don't want to run it.  So, for example, if you run:

```
EXEC DynamicUpdateSQLFromFieldList @field1='col1', @field2='col2', @field3='col3'
```

or

```
EXEC DynamicUpdateSQLFromFieldList @field1='col1', @field2='col2', @field3='col3', @RunMe=0
```

the SQL produced will be:

```
UPDATE Temp
SET Temp.RECID = Phy.RECID
FROM TempTable Temp INNER JOIN Physicians Phy
ON Phy.col1 = Temp.col1 AND
   Phy.col2 = Temp.col2 AND
   Phy.col3 = Temp.col3;
```

If you run this line:

```
EXEC DynamicUpdateSQLFromFieldList @field1='col1', @field2='col2', @field3='col3', @RunMe=1
```

It will perform the update.  If you wanted it to be more secure, you could whitelist the incoming field names against the sys tables to make sure the columns actually exist in each table before you execute any code.